# F3 hive ($f3) undefined inside view file

Tags: view, fat-free-framework

Starting a new Fat Free Framework (F3) project and having a problem that the hive ($f3) global variable is not defined/available inside a view file. According to the docs, $f3 should be globally available. The trying to access $f3 inside a view file, I get an error.  So, here's the code:

In index.php:

```
$f3->route('GET /','SomeController->index');
```

In SomeController.php:

```
class SiteController
{

    public function index($f3)
    {
        $f3->set('title','Index');
        View::instance()->render('indexView.php');
    }

}
```

In indexView.php

```
echo $f3->get('title');
```

Output

```
Internal Server Error

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

I get get around this by explicitly passing $f3 to the view like so:

```
View::instance()->render('indexView.php', 'text/html', array('f3'=>$f3));
```

But, your not supposed to have to do this.  According to the docs:

```
string render ( string $file [, string $mime = 'text/html' [, array $hive = NULL ]] )
Note:
If no data $hive is provided, the global F3 hive is used.
```

Answer (score 3):

The hive content is extracted, HTML-encoded and passed to the view, but the whole `$f3` instance is not.

So when running:

```php
$f3->set('title','Index');
$f3->set('text','Hello');
View::instance()->render('indexView.php');
```

The following variables will be available from the view:

- `$title`
- `$text`

But `$f3` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to keep your view variables compartmentalized, but this depends on your opinions regarding MVC structure.

However, if you do need to access the $f3 HIVE inside a view you can do it by simply adding at the top of your view.

```
global $f3;

// now you can use the HIVE
echo $f3->get('myVar');
```